# Se puede desactivar el modo oscuro?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

se que no estoy aportando ningún código ni nada de referencia, pero ya que he buscado en internet y no he encontrado una respuesta he decidido preguntar por aquí. Básicamente estoy desarrollando un proyecto muy simple en **Android Studio** con Java, lo que pasa es que he hecho un layout con ***cardview*** y estas cardview tienen un fondo blanco.

Al compilarlo en un telefono que tiene activado el **Modo Oscuro** siempre se ve negro, igual que el fondo o incluso las letras que esten en blanco. He probado en poner el layout en light y muchas otras opciones, pero siempre se ve negro, obviamente en un telefono sin modo oscuro se ve bien. Hay alguna manera de quizas desactivar que siempre cualquier cosa en blanco la deje en blanco si tu lo dejas así ? No se si me explicado.

Comment: Si que te has explicado, pero creo que tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. La mía es: programa tu app usando dicha característica, de esa forma si el cliente tiene activado el modo oscuro, tu app sabrá que hacer y mostrará el color adecuado. Saludos

Comment: Agrega lo que investigaste o trataste para obtener mejores respuestas, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediante programación se puede hacer con `setForceDarkAllowed()` (Esto es en ventanas especificas)

Tambien puedes hacerlo desde la vista XML agregando : `android:forceDarkAllowed`

[Mas información](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6488033-android-10-dark-theme-getting-started#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20disable,the%20view%20in%20the%20XML.)

Answer (score 0):

Esto se escribe en el metodo onCreate de cada activity
Si solo deseas desactivar el modo oscuro solo usaras el primer case del switch

```
int nightModeFlags = contexto.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (nightModeFlags) {
   case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES: 
        /* si esta activo el modo oscuro lo desactiva */         
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        reak;
   case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
   /* si esta desactivado el modo oscuro lo activa */
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        break;
}
```